# my server call v2/checkout/orders/ paypal sandbox return 404 Not Found

Tags: paypal

1:  i used ios client create a order, get response as below

CurrencyCode: USD

Amount: 21.47

Short Description: Hipster clothing

Intent: sale

Processable: Already processed

Display: $21.47

Confirmation: {

```
client =     {

    environment = sandbox;

    "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.18.1";

    platform = iOS;

    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";

};

response =     {

    "create_time" = "2019-12-16T12:12:48Z";

    id = "PAYID-LX3XJQI4U759055JE198303J";

    intent = sale;

    state = approved;

};

"response_type" = payment;
```

}

Details: Subtotal: 12.98, Shipping: 5.99, Tax: 2.5

Shipping Address: (null)

Invoice Number: (null)

Custom: (null)

Soft Descriptor: (null)

Payee email: (null)

BN code: (null)

Item: '{1|Old jeans with holes|4.99|USD|Hip-00037}'

Item: '{1|Free rainbow patch|0.00|USD|Hip-00066}'

Item: '{1|Long-sleeve plaid shirt (mustache not included)|7.99|USD|Hip-00291}'

2:  i can see  transaction in  https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/

sb-g8ehg personal example

Receipt for Your Payment to Doe John

16 De[Removed. Phone #s not permitted]/td>

3:  my server side want to get payment details , but 404

curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/PAYID-LX3XJQI4U759055JE198303J -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer A21AAHMxaNfgH67r9uGcKMtCHHMo-VDQHf4WGBEZIbzEtBo7_bSMXArvTYGEUub_gT3s2_XRCJJNbgdXTd9mmZiANBs2URVUg"

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.

- Trying 173.0.82.78...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem

  CApath: none
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-SHA256
- ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
- Server certificate:
- subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
- start date: Aug 21 00:00:00 2018 GMT
- expire date: Aug 20 12:00:00 2020 GMT
- subjectAltName: host "api.sandbox.paypal.com" matched cert's "api.sandbox.paypal.com"
- issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert Global CA G2
- SSL certificate verify ok.

> GET /v2/checkout/orders/PAYID-LX3XJQI4U759055JE198303J HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Authorization: Bearer A21AAHMxaNfgH67r9uGcKMtCHHMo-VDQHf4WGBEZIbzEtBo7_bSMXArvTYGEUub_gT3s2_XRCJJNbgdXTd9mmZiANBs2URVUg

>

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

< Content-Length: 385

< Content-Type: application/json

< Date: Mon, 16 De[Removed. Phone #s not permitted]GMT

< Paypal-Debug-Id: d59bbbad78a81

<

- Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact

{"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","details":[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again."}],"message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"d59bbbad78a81","links":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear the SDK you are using implements v2/checkout/orders, and so when you request that PAYID it is 404 Not Found

Perhaps that SDK implements v1/payments or v2/payments instead

Comment: yes,  below it's works for me  

curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LX4MK4Q1YN71424EF0189251 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer A21AAHp5HClgyokWjVyBQYg4n98P8mqx2STgx6NAtjTk0-j8TnDIo_AoewevVoK4r-TlpW7iEJOyqDEkIz3eDCI1Tt4sLZOzw"